# What is the equation and mechanism of Hopkins-Cole Test reaction?

Tags: biochemistry, amino-acids

The Hopkins-Cole reaction or glyoxylic acid reaction, is a chemical test used for qualitative detecting of tryptophan in protein solutions.

tryptophan + glyoxylic acid + sulfuric acid  >  violet product

I know the chemical formulas of reactants, but I could not find the product formula and a mechanism for the reaction.